# Sitecore context user lost in custom MVC Route

Tags: mvc, authentication

I'm having a strange issue with my `Sitecore.Context.User`. I set up a custom MVC route for a controller that looks like this

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("accounts api", "accountsapi/{action}", new {controller = "Accounts", action = "{action}"});
    }
}
```

When I hit one of the controller actions using regular Sitecore MVC, the `Sitecore.Context.User` is authenticated and all my cookies etc. are present as I expected. However, if I access the same controller over the route that I have set up, the `Sitecore.Context.User` is the anonymous user (even when I'm already logged in) and I can see that I get a completely different set of cookies showing up (the auth cookie isn't 1 of them).

I first noticed the issue because I was attempting to authenticate over the route and noticed that the context was immediately lost when accessing the context via the normal sitecore routing process.

The routing is initialized via a pipeline like this

```
public class LoadCustomRoutes
{
    public void Process(PipelineArgs args)
    {
        Log.Info("Loading custom routes", this);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Processor loaded like this:

```
<initialize>
    <processor type="ABC.Project.Common.Pipelines.LoadCustomRoutes, ABC.Project.Common" patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Pipelines.Loader.EnsureAnonymousUsers, Sitecore.Kernel']" />
</initialize>
```

Is this expected behaviour? The `AccountsController` is a `SitecoreController` so it shouldn't be affected by any of the WebAPI drawbacks (as far as I know). I feel like I'm missing something but I'm not sure what it is. Any ideas?

Comment: Is you API url and site url the same?

Comment: Yes it is the same domain

Comment: Can you try using a controller as your base instead of Sitecore controller. I never use the Sitecore controller class and it works for me. Do you use the Sitecore initialize class to register your mvc routes?

Comment: I'm just using a regular `Pipeline` class that executes custom code to register the routes. Not sure what the `initialize` class is that you are referring to. I'll try a regular controller to see what that does.

Comment: @Rondel: Seems your patch configs need to be updated with [Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Loader.InitializeRoutes], did you tried similar way? If not, have a look https://community.sitecore.net/technical_blogs/b/sitecorejohn_blog/posts/fun-facts-about-mvc-route-initialization-in-the-sitecore-asp-net-cms

Comment: How do you test your api request? Is it a call from javascript? Different cookies almost looks like some custom way of sending the request to the api

Comment: @ChrisvandeSteeg It did turn out to be an issue in the JS where it wasn't sending or accepting cookies. *sigh* Lesson learned though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this was a classic case of chasing a red herring's shadow down a rabbit hole. The actual issue here had nothing to do with the custom route configuration. The authentication call was using the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to trigger the request. Upon further inspection, I noticed that the cookies were being returned in the response correctly, but were not being saved automatically. From the fetch docs:

> By default, fetch won't send or receive any cookies from the server,
>   resulting in unauthenticated requests if the site relies on
>   maintaining a user session (to send cookies, the credentials init
>   option must be set).

The fix for this was to add a `credentials: 'include'` property to the fetch call so that it saved cookies (even though the domain was the same).

```
fetch('/accountsapi/login', {
                    method: "post",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
                        "Content-Type": "application/json"
                    },
                    credentials: 'include',
                    body: JSON.stringify(valueObj)
                })
```

Now things work like I would have expected... So nothing specific to sitecore on this one.